# Countif Formula With Beginning of The Month Till Today Date Range (Google Sheet)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

the objective of the formula is to count the number of certain dates from 1st of the month till today. Ex:

A1  10/5

A2  10/6

A3  10/11

A4  10/29

A5  10/20

Today is 10/14

I want to count the number of dates before today, which is 3.
The formula I could come up with is as below, please tell me whats wrong with it.

> =countif(A1:A5;">=TODAY()-30";A1:A5;"<=TODAY()")

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Function will be placed outside of double quotation. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"<" & TODAY())
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, however, sorry it doesn't work.

Comment: Then may be your data are not true date (dates entered as string). Can you share a copy of sample sheet?

Comment: Never mind, turns out I just needed to change the '," to ";" and the formula works. Thank you!

Comment: @HadrianWangka Oh! That depends on regional settings. Glad it works.